# Unable to Queue Build - Visual Studio Build - TFS - On Premesis

Tags: tfsbuild

Firstly, we didn't have any build on TFS 2013. After upgrade to TFS 2015 with update 2.1 , I downloaded a Build Agent and configured on different server. I have followed  the steps with MSDN article on setting up Build on TFS 2015. When I Queue the build we receive Build Failed message with  the following

*Unable to obtain an authenticated token for running job Build with plan type Build and identifier Project Collection Build Service (TEAM FOUNDATION).*

I have done the following to try it to make build Working Windows service runs on (Domain\TFSBuild)

1. Added "Project Build Service" to Agent Queue Users
2. Added TFSBuild to Agent Queue Users.
3. Added TFSBuild to have access contributor permission to Project collection
4. Added "Project Build Service"  to queue, manage edit and read source on Project collection.
5. I have made the TFSBuild  service account to have interactive logon permission.

All the above didn't work.  I have also tried solution

Any suggestion or please help is much appreciated.

Comment: Same issue here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f55994eb-8316-43f1-b7d9-3306bb665bfc/issues-with-buildvnext-after-upgrading-to-team-foundation-server-2015-update-1?forum=tfsbuild

Comment: Thanks Eddie,  I tried everything suggested in the MSFT. it didn't work for me. May be I'm missing something...

Answer (score 2):

Finally, found the answer for this. It is to do with TFS service account created on the domain. For some reason account logged in had a temp profile. after deleting profile and logging back as created proper local profile on the server at c:\users....

Comment: This worked for me too. Please mark as accepted solution (for me, I couldn't delete the profile, I had to reboot the server before the temp. profile became a local profile).